# Pass an Image from Activity to Adapter Class

Tags: android, image, android-activity

I am trying to **pass an Image from SingleItem activity to CartAdapter**, but i am facing problem, while trying to pass an Item Image.

I want whenever user do click on Add to Cart button in SingleItem activity, *need to send Item Image and Strings from SingleItem.java to CartAdapter.java*

**Note:** Able to pass String but trying to pass an Item Image, I am missing some code onButtonClick in SingleItem.java

Like using below line i am getting value for Item Title

```
     myTitle = txttitle.getText().toString();
 Log.d(SingleItem.LOG_TAG, "Title :: " + myTitle);
```

but i don't know how to get an Item Image

```
    myThumb = // here what i should need to write
```

See my code below:

**SingleItem.java::**

```
                                // below i need your help                                
                                myThumb = // here i want to write code to get Image,
                                          // like above i have written code to get String
```

Comment: Hii.... From where you retrieve your image?? @ myThumb =

Comment: @mitB hello i don't know how to retrieve but i used this to show an image in SingleItem.java : imageLoader.DisplayImage(thumb_url, imgv);  and now i just want to get that image that's it, please check SingleItem.java activity code

Comment: Why would you want to transfer a bitmap from one activity to another ? why not just clean/release the bitmap and recreate it on the other activity ? Or you can serialize it and save it on disk.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sending Bitmap, write the Bitmap to file system and send its location so that the other activity can read the Bitmap from that location.

Sending large data through intents could cause ANRs

Comment: Do you think reading and writing on file system is an efficient way, this could be approach if Bitmap is quite large i.e 4 to 5 MB, but for images upto 1 MB its not a good approach

Comment: Yes u r right. it depends on size of the BitMap. And of course if both activities are in the same process writing to file system is not a good idea, use of 'Singleton' is better.

Answer (score 1):

`Bitmap` Class implements `Parcelable` so you can pass your Bitmap from one class to another class but i will not recommend this. In my experience in case of large Bitmaps, this could cause ANR in android, you can use Singleton Pattern for Interclass communication for heavy objects, if you are using `Singleton` make sure you read multithreading issues.

Comment: I would do this. Its neat, effective and does not loose memory. But be careful about reading before writing, thread sync issues.

Comment: If you are following android's parcelable approach ok, if you want to use Singleton pattern, Create a Singleton class http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern and create an instance variable of type Bitmap in your singleton class, than from where your first activity initialize that Bitmap and in seccond Activity use it. if you are using Android OS below than 4.0 you have to release bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Use Hash Map. In hash map put bitmap with  key and pass this hash map to the `Adapter`. And Get that hash map in adapter class.